# Force generate a new session or lock a session ID to a client when using the same login for Windows Virtual Machines versus taking over empty session?

Tags: windows, virtualization, rdp, login, session

### Situation

Our engineering group generates new Windows VMs from a template that uses a generic admin user.  Through the course of a project that user is used in multiple, parallel sessions by several engineers that are making modifications to code or configuration.

Most engineers utilize the old **Microsoft RDP Terminal (mstsc)** or the new **Windows 10 Microsoft Remote Desktop Application** (version 10.2.1810.0).  Some use **VMware Remote Client**.

### Issue

When sessions are left open another user may log in and inadvertently take over another person's active session with in progress changes and notes.

**Note: This issue is observed from all methods.**

### Workarounds

1. When it's 2 people, one user disconnects and the other launches task manager to connect over to their desired session. More than 3 people means a discussion determining who is on what session.
2. Save their active files and continue using the session as is.

### Desired Solutions

1. Locking down sessions by client name or prioritize client name for session re-entry.
   [Users tab of Windows Task Manager with same user for multiple sessions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hk9Zs.png)
2. Ability to create ad-hoc new sessions when landing in to someone else's session inadvertently.

Comment: Why don't you have each user use a dedicated named user account rather then all using the same username?

Comment: The multiple session / single user current method works 90% of the time.  The additional configuration for superuser accounts with the pre-installed applications on the VM template would mean additional non-project configuration work.  The "Client name" is a known value in Windows.  I thought there could be a setting like "prioritize the session assignment by client name last on session" or "lock session by client name" or "generate new session if not last client name" but I haven't been able to locate any options like that.